# Change Button Color when EditText is empty - android

Tags: android, button, colors, android-edittext

I want to know if it's possible to change button's color when a particular edittext is empty or not empty. Like when edittext is empty, the button says "ADD" and when its not empty it says "CHANGE". Can someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to change Button Color or Button Text?

Comment: Button Text and Color. Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About `Button Text` set like:

```
if(editText.getText().toString.length()>0){
yourbutton.setText("Change");
}else{
yourbutton.setText("Add");
}
```

And if you implement `EditText addTextChangedListener` then

```
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence str, int start, int count, int after)    {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence str, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable str) {
             if(str.toString().trim().length()>0){
                 yourbutton.setText("Change");
             }else{
                 yourbutton.setText("Add");
             }
        }
    });
```

And you can also set `Button Text Color` dynamically like:

```
  yourbutton.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
```

and For More information go to: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html

Comment: thanks but when I input a text to the edittext, the button doesn't change, it only changes when I refresh it. Is it possible that it chnges automatically without refreshing the page?

Comment: @jajaja you try to change it programmatically as per i yourbutton.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

Comment: Thanks! It's working now! Vote up and check for you! Thank you! :)

Comment: @jajaja that was great.

Answer (score 2):

```
// try this way 

**activity_main.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtValue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddOrChange"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Add"/>
</LinearLayout>


**MyActivity.java**
 public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    private EditText edtvalue;
    private Button btnAddOrChange;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edtvalue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtValue);
        btnAddOrChange = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddOrChange);

        edtvalue.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                 if(s.toString().trim().length()>0){
                     btnAddOrChange.setText("Change");
                 }else{
                     btnAddOrChange.setText("Add");
                 }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

To change `Button's` text and `background color` do something like this

```
urEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                 if(s.toString().trim().length()>0){
                     urBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREY);
                     urBtn.setText("Change");
                 }else{
                     urBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                     urBtn.setText("Add");
                 }
            }
        });
```